# Substr in AWK returns empty line in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having problems with this line that uses AWK

```sh
apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/ {print substr($2, 0, 1)}'
```

In a machine with Ubuntu `18.10` I get as result `3` as I expect but in another machine with Ubuntu `18.04` I get an `empty` line.

In Ubuntu 18.04:

```sh
j@minimal:~$ apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/ {print $2}'
2.7.1-3
j@minimal:~$ apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/ {print substr($2, 0, 1)}'

j@minimal:~$
```

In Ubuntu `18.10`

```sh
krono@vulcania:~$ apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/ {print $2}'
3.0.2-1~cosmic
krono@vulcania:~$ apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/ {print substr($2, 0, 1)}'
3
krono@vulcania:~$
```

How come in Ubuntu 18.04 I get an empty line instead of `2` ?

Comment: Works fine on my 18.04. I'm using GNU awk 4.1.4.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu with me but try changing `substr($0,1,1)` in your 18.04 2nd code once? If it's index starts from 1?

Comment: I suspect that the apt-cache result is different in each environment.  Try posting the intermediate results - for instance `apt-cache policy fish | awk '/Candidate/' `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[POSIX awk specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) defines `substr` as follows:

> **substr**(s, m[, n])
>
> Return the at most n-character substring of s that begins at position m, **numbering from 1**. ...

That means, your script is incorrect; there is no such position in a string as zero. And Ubuntu 18.04 uses an old version of **mawk** which can't handle such usage of `substr` (it's fixed in further versions though, see [mawk changelog #20090726](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#t20090726)) as default implementation. So, you need to use:

```
substr($2,1,1)
```